# Horizontal margin too big on newly created Expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, jsx

I just created a React Native app with Expo using `expo init`. Everything went fine. Then I went on and created a Home screen like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    state = {
        searchText: ""
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View 
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: 'white'
                }}
            >
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    value={this.state.searchText}
                    onChangeText={ (searchText) => this.setState({ searchText }) }
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I added it to my `AppNavigator`...

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({ 
    Home: HomeScreen
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

...which I in turn added to `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => { };

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    console.warn(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Now, my problem is that my app looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the horizontal margins are way too big, but I never set them to be like that. What am I doing wrong? I want the `TextInput` to stretch across the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your HomeScreen Component will be as wide as its contents. You did not specify the width of the main View, therefore, it adjusted itself to be as wide the components inside. What you can do to resolve this issue is that you must provide `width` property in your Top level View's style.
And in order to get the Width of the screen, you can import `Dimensions` from react-native and use that like below:

`const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;`

and finally, you can assign the `windowWidth` to your view like so:

`style={{flex:1, width: windowWidth,  backgroundColor: 'white'}}`

Comment: I tried your solution in both `App.js` and my Home screen, but to no avail, the problem still remains as if nothing changed.

Comment: It should have worked. Try adding `alignSelf: "stretch"` with `width: "windowWidth"` to your `HomeScreen`'s main `View`.

Comment: I know, it's really strange because it should be working. I tried your comment as well but same problem. There must be something else wrong somewhere..